# Solving the system $\ln x=4\ln y$, $\log_3x=2+2\log_3y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> Solve the following system of equations:
>
> $$\ln(x)=4\ln(y)$$
> $$\log_3x=2+2\log_3y$$

Here is my attempt to solve this problem. I rewrote the system as:

$e^4+y=x$ and $9=\frac{x}{y^2}$. When I tried to solve this system, I am not getting the correct answer, which is $(81, 3)$.

So, any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: First equation becomes $x=y^4$.

Comment: For $a\in\mathbb R$ and $x\in\mathbb R^+$: $$a\log x=\log x^a.$$

Comment: Oh. I see. Thank you. I went too far.. I set $\ln{x}=4\ln{y}$ as $\ln{x}/\ln{y}=4$ and so forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing the conversion correctly.

$\ln x = 4\ln y \implies e^{\ln x} = e^{4 \ln y}$ and as $4\ln y = \ln y^4$ or because $e^{4\ln y} = (e^{\ln y})^4$ we have $e^{4\ln y} = y^4$ so $\implies x = y^4$.

$\log_3 x = 2+ 2\log_3 y\implies 3^{\log 3 x} =3^{2+2\log_3 y}\implies 3^{\log_3 x} = 3^2\cdot 3^{2\log_3 y}\implies x= 9\cdot 3^{2\log_3 y}$ and again because $2\log_3 y = \log_3 y^2$ or because $3^{2\log_3 y} = (3^{\log_3 y})^2$ we have $x = 9y^2$.

And that's that.

$x = y^4$ and $x = 9y^2$ so....

You need more practice (practice, practice, practice) on your log identities.

Practice practice practice.

Practice until your eyes bleed.

Comment: I went too far.. I set lnx=4lny as lnx/lny=4 and so forth. But, thank you for your help.

Comment: Or $$\ln x=4\ln y\iff \ln x =\ln y^4 \iff x=y^4, x>0,y>0$$ We need just to cancel $\ln $. Or $\ln \frac {x}{y^4}=0\implies x=y^4$

Comment: @Lily Do not memorize formulas.  Just make sure you know where the formulas come from.

Comment: @lonestudent Although you should certainly try to know where formulae come from, I think that often it is extremely helpful to memorise formulae. For example, knowing the quadratic formula enables you to deal with any quadratic in about 10 seconds if the coefficients are reasonably small. The same goes for standard derivatives, integrals, trig identities and more.

Comment: @A-LevelStudent Yes knowing where formulas come from triggers memorization.  We all know the formula for the quadratic equation by heart.  But the man who doesn't know where this formula came from can probably forget it many years later.

Comment: My method is *understand* them so that you can derive them yourself, the derive and derive them and memorize them through the act of deriving them.  The harder ones to remember such as $\log_a b = \frac 1{\log_b a}$ or $\log_{b^k} c= \frac {\log_b c}k$ (or is it the other way around???  $\log_{b} \frac ck = \sqrt[k]{\log_b c}$  How do I remember which is which?!) become managable if you can derive them.  .... and as they are just to inverse of exponents they are all straight forward and logical.